# Do the pH and other ions affect the hydrolysis of ATP

Tags: biochemistry, thermodynamics, ph

ATP hydrolizes to ADP and phosphate in a strongly exergonic reaction and is used for energy transfer and short-term storage in cells.

ATP is stable inside a cell, so a significant activation energy must be necessary for the reaction.

However, the English Wikipedia article implies that stability of ATP is not a given, but depends strongly on the properties of the surrouding solution:

- *"ATP is highly soluble in water and is quite stable in solutions between pH 6.8 and 7.4, but is rapidly hydrolysed at extreme pH."* and
- *"ATP is an unstable molecule in unbuffered water, in which it hydrolyses to ADP and phosphate."*

How does the pH affect the hydrolysis of ATP?
Why is it even relevant if the solution is buffered or not? (Do the ions stabilize the molecule somehow?)
Are there other effects that influence stability in animal cells?

Comment: Welcome to Biology SE. This is a reasonable question, although perhaps more chemistry than biology. However I have altered the title to include the key factor you are concerned about — pH. That will help others know what your question is about, and thus whether they feel they may be able to help you. It is also important for archiving purposes.

Comment: Actually, It seems that both the right ph and the existance of a buffer in the solution is required, so that needs clarification as well. 
Sorry I asked two questions instead of one, but it might be related. 
I did not ask at Chemistry SE, as there might be something else going on inside cells that might influence stability of ATP.

Comment: I guess alkaline hydolysis will happen via a mechanism similar to alkaline hydrolysis of phosphodiester bond in RNA.

Comment: I've changed the title to the more precise hydrolysis, because that's what the Wikipedia quotes refer to. I would imagine @WYSIWYG is right about alkaline hydrolysis. I don't know about acid hydrolysis.

Comment: I'm not sure how the activation energy would be affected by pH, but it is well known that the equilibrium is shifted by pH since the various phosphates have different pKa values. See for example http://www.jbc.org/content/193/1/425.citation

Answer (score 1):

Stability of ATP is largely due to Mg<sup>2+</sup>. ATP in cell is actually Mg<sub>2</sub>ATP<sup>2-</sup>
The Mg ions stability the negative charges on the phosphates. pH is also important of course, but Mg is key, hence you see Mg<sup>2+</sup> all the time in biochemical reactions where ATP is involved.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question. The question asked why extremes of pH affect the stability (the quote is for hydrolysis) of ATP. The fact that Mg ions interact with the phosphate negative charges has nothing to do with hydrolysis outside the range of pHs quoted.

Comment: @David. aside from the question " are there other effects that influence stability in animal cells.

Comment: Mg2+ is there as a counter-ion and is required so the ATP is in the right conformation to bind to the active site of enzymes. All this talk of "stability" is unscientific waffle. And the Wikipedia entry is of no relevance to biology talking about the need for buffers and suitable pH. That's the milieu of the cell. It's really the sort of thing a chemist would write about preparing solutions in the lab.

Comment: @ David: My question title was changed by a moderator. The answer matches my original question "Why is ATP stable in cells?".

Comment: @SciEnt: Thank you for your answer! Do you have any sources readily available?

Comment: @user25269 Any biochemistry textbook really. But one i have personally read. Lehninger Principles of Biochemistry. By Nelson & Cox 6th Ed.

Comment: @David: I'm no expert, but I don't see why Mg2+ cannot stabilize ATP in solution. Could you please elaborate?  
Of course, ATP is (kinetically) stable in the milieu of the cell. However, it is unstable without a buffer and hydrolysis occurs without any enzyme or other catalyst.
I wanted to know which component/property of the cell milieu is responsible for ATP being stable in the cell, as the reason is not evident for me. 
Also, please keep it civil.

Comment: @user25269 The only reason ATP would be "unstable" without a buffer is because when the free acid were  dissolved in water the solution would become acidic and (apparently) be hydrolysed. As the cellular milieu is buffered by a multitude of things ( especially bicarbonate) this problem does not arise. And stop talking about "stability". ATP does not undergo alkaline hydrolysis at cellular pH because it is only slightly alkaline and the concentration of hydroxyl ions is insufficient. You seem to be obsessed by a problem that doesn't exist.

Comment: The question is about pH. Your answer is about Mg. It basically qualifies as "insufficient explanation".

Comment: @TomD "I wonder how many of the downvoters to this answer realize the critical importance of Mg in all ATP-dependent biological reactions." I certainly do, but, as I have written, I regard it as irrelevant, because the question (not the title) was about the hydrolysis of ATP and something called its stability (degradation of the purine ring?). If you think Mg ions somehow prevent the hydrolysis or degradation of ATP, rather than just being the counter-ion required in enzymic reactions, please cite sources.

Answer (score 1):

OK. Let’s answer the questions you pose:

**How does the pH affect the hydrolysis of ATP?**

High concentrations of hydrogen ions or hydroxyl ions (“extremes of pH” — as you quote) cause acid or alkaline hydrolysis. The mechanism of alkaline hydrolysis is presumably through a cyclic intermediate, as with [the hydrolysis of RNA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RNA_hydrolysis). Acid hydrolysis of ATP requires very low pH — for example it has been studied in 3M perchloric acid — and the mechanism is quite complex, according to work published by [Hutchings *et. al.* in 1981](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/bi00523a025).

**Why is it even relevant if the solution is buffered or not?**

In unbuffered solutions the pH may easily deviate from the physiological range. This is a practical consideration of work *in vitro*. Physiological and cellular systems are highly buffered by a variety of ions and even macromolecules so the problem does not arise.

**Are there other effects that influence stability in animal cells?**

You are mistaken in your assumption that there is a particular need to prevent hydrolysis of ATP within animal cells. This appears to be based on a misunderstanding of a Wikipedia entry which is more concerned with the chemistry of ATP rather than its situation in the cell.

Comment: @TomD — ATP is an important metabolite, and its generation and the coupling of its hydrolysis to chemical, electrochemical and mechanical processes is important. Whether it is “the basis of life” any more than DNA, RNA, proteins, lipids, NAD etc. is an irrelevant and fruitless question. What I maintain is that the problems Nature had to solve with respect to ATP were those already mentioned. Its activation energy and chemistry are such that there is no tendency for its spontaneous hydrolysis at physiological pH, so preventing this is not a problem and certainly not the “the basis of life”.